# Can a Django project made in Python be used by Jython?

Tags: python, django, jython

I have a Django project that was written in Python first.  Then we realized that there might be an advantage to using Jython.

After spending a day or two fiddling with Jython trying to get the original project to work in Jython, I realized that perhaps the issue was that I was trying to run a Django project generated with Python.  I was thinking maybe the django-jython project might only affect all Django code generated using Jython.

Could this be the case?  The error that pops up when I'm trying to run *jython manage.py syncdb* is *django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb* except that django-jython is supposed to make it so if my config says *'ENGINE': 'doj.backends.zxjdbc.mysql'* then it will run okay.  Oh, and my classpath does include the mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar

Any help?  Tips?  Criticisms?

**EDIT**: Oh, sorry.  In Jython, I have

```
Django : 1.3.1 
Jython : 2.5.2 
django-jython : 1.3
```

Databases look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'doj.backends.zxjdbc.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'django_abcd',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'abcdef',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'ghijkl123',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: So I think I found some of the problem.  Jython sets up it's own stuff properly, but when I add things to JYTHONPATH there's conflicts created (specifically when I include the original python site-packages to the JYTHONPATH).  Instead of Jython telling me that there's module name MySQLdb, it's telling me that it's missing Grappelli now.

So in a way, this question is solved I think.

Thanks for your time everyone.  :)

Comment: Need more info: Django version, and copy and paste your `DATABASES` setting. You hinted at it, but please post all relevant settings as is.

Comment: The error you're getting strikes me as weird for a django-jython install. `MySQLdb` is the module name for the Python MySQL connector. The engine you're using should complain with "Error loading zxJDBC module", if it can't find the jar file. Make sure you restart any webservers that are running, and delete any `*.pyc` for good measure.

Comment: I don't have any *.pyc files or web servers.  This is all running locally at the moment.  That's why my question is here-- I didn't rewrite anything in Jython, rather I just used my existing Django Python project and tried to run it in Jython.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use pure Python apps then it should work between both CPython and Jython provided you modify the database backend. If you have C modules in any of your apps then you will need to port the relevant code to use Python or Java libraries instead.

Comment: I thought using django-jython was the modification necessary to integrate Django and Jython.  Is there something else I might have to do, or have forgotten to set up?